# How do I move our slide library from one site to another?

Tags: slidelibrary

We're creating a brand new site and want to re-use some of the parts and pieces of our old SharePoint site (both 2010 versions). I can't remember how to move the Slide Library so that I don't have to recreate. Any suggestions would be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You can save the library as template and move it to the new site. [Here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/copy-or-move-a-library-by-using-a-library-template-HA101814157.aspx) is the Microsoft documentation to do the same.

In brief :

1) Go to your slide library settings, Under Permissions and management tab click **Save library as template**

2) Provide a name to the template and hit OK. The template will be saved in the list template gallery.

3) Go to the site settings of the site and under galleries download the list template you saved from the **List template gallery**

4) Go to the site where you want to restore the library.

5) Navigate to the list template gallery of the site and upload the template.

Now you can create a library with this template.